# Rsync --link-dest option for single file

Tags: rsync

I have been using rsync with --link-dest option to backup directories.
I want to achieve the same thing with single files, i.e., I want to copy file srcfile to dstfile knowing that I have a previous version of the file named prevfile in destfile directory.

For directories I use: `rsync -a --link-dest=prevdir srcdir dstdir`

However link-dest can only take directory values. It cannot take files. I would like to do something like: `rsync -a --link-dest=prevfile srcfile dstfile`

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity this doesn't work--I agree it would be very useful.  But all you have to do to simulate it is make the link yourself:

```
ln prevfile dstfile
rsync -a srcfile dstfile
```

By the way, I filed this as a bug: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8594